# Hello World in Ansible + Python is not working

Tags: python, ansible

I'm getting started in writing custom modules using python for ansible. I used a tutorial like this https://medium.com/@heenashree2010/create-a-custom-module-with-ansible-python-6285874a09b4

**main.yaml**

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_prompt:
   - name: giveName
     prompt: "Please provide your name"
     private: no
     failed_when: giveName is undefined
  tasks:
  - name: Python Execution
    testing: yourName={{ giveName }}
    register: result
  - debug: var=result
```

**testing.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
import os, json
import re, sys

def firstProg(text):
  text1 = "Hello " + text
  return text1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fields = {
  "yourName": {"required": True, "type": "str"}
  }
  module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=fields)
  yourName = os.path.expanduser(module.params['yourName'])
  newName = firstProg(yourName)
  module.exit_json(msg=newName)
```

When I try to execute the ansible playbook I get the following error:

```
[ebeid@localhost hello-world-custom-module]$ ansible-playbook main.yaml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ebeid/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ebeid/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ebeid/env/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAYBOOK: main.yaml ************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in main.yaml
Please provide your name: ebeid

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ebeid/ansible-sandbox/hello-world-custom-module/main.yaml:1
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ebeid
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ebeid && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894="` echo /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/ebeid/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-32250T4H7Md/tmpnuPOdr TO /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894/ /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/home/ebeid/env/bin/python /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725618.58-95756223105894/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [Python Execution] ********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ebeid/ansible-sandbox/hello-world-custom-module/main.yaml:10
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ebeid
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ebeid && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142="` echo /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/ebeid/ansible-sandbox/hello-world-custom-module/library/testing.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/ebeid/ansible-sandbox/hello-world-custom-module/library/testing.py TO /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/AnsiballZ_testing.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-32250T4H7Md/tmpfsVxQ3 TO /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/args
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/ /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/AnsiballZ_testing.py /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/args && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/AnsiballZ_testing.py /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/args && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: /home/ebeid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567725620.8-68546874702142/AnsiballZ_testing.py: cannot execute binary file\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 126
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

It seems to be the python file is not recognized as executable file. Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Execute playbook with `-vvv` argument and c/p THE TEXT, please.

Comment: The horrible typo in the error message [seems to be fixed now.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/2ebc4e1e7eda61f133d9425872e2a858bae92ec4/lib/ansible/inventory/manager.py#L298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the module format and documentation guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html#python-shebang-utf-8-coding), ansible modules written in python **must** start with `#!/usr/bin/python` whereas yours starts with `#! /usr/bin/env python`

You can see the [`_get_shebang` wizardry](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.4/lib/ansible/executor/module_common.py#L894-L896) used to sniff out the interpreter and replace it with their own value (traditionally the value of `ansible_python_interpreter`, which is a discovered fact or you can also set it in your playbook/ad-hoc run)

They claim the 2nd line must be `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` but I actually can't recall ever doing that, so your experience may vary. I would suggest doing as they say, until you know for sure it works, and then decide whether to keep it or not.